# Hibernate OSX like Windows

Tags: macos, multi-boot, hibernate, osx-mavericks

I have two instances of OSX Mavericks on two partitions on my MacBook Pro. I need to be able to Hibernate one instance and boot into another - like what you can do with two Windows installations on a PC.

Is this at all possible with OSX?

Answer (score 1):

Good news:
You can set hibernation mode from the command line:

```
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25
```

With that setting, any time your computer sleeps, it will hibernate instead.  You can then hibernate it manually by choosing Apple manu -> Sleep, and it will go down to hibernate and power off.

---

Bad news:
When your Mac hibernates it writes a value to the PRAM that indicates as such (at least I think that's how it remembers). There's no way to Option+boot the computer to get into Windows at that point.  At least not on my Mac anyway  :-(  It always resumes from hibernate when I power it back on.  Doesn't even make the startup chime.

If anyone knows how to get around that, I'd love to know.